# Transiesta electrodes with GNR structures

Tags: siesta, electronic-transport

As far as I understand, it would be better to use metallic electrodes in a Transiesta calculation and avoid the usage of semiconducting electrodes. It should be related to the bad screening of the latter and the consequent usage of very big systems (along with the definition of Fermi energy in semiconductors and so on).

Having said this, I would like to check the transport properties of some GNRs. I have already done some calculations on a doped monolayer graphene using graphene as electrodes, like the following:

[image]

and I would like to study the same but in a nanoribbon case.
Should one keep using graphene (thus not nano-ribbons) as electrode also with GNR to avoid problems in the calculation?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but can you update us now that it has been 6+ months since you asked this question? Have you found the answer? Are you still actively in need of an answer?